# Dropping and creating a MySQL view in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I'm having a problem with some PHP / MySQL code.

I need a view called gameview for a Star Wars game I'm writing.

If I created the view in MySQL then the code runs perfectly.  However, I need this view to be dropped every time the game starts.  So if I start without the view "gameview" present in the DB, the page cannot be displayed due to the view not existing.  However, the moment I manually add the view into MySQL, it works.  I can't see why.

Class code

```
<?php

class gameView
{
    protected $Conn;

    public function __construct($Conn)
    {
        $this->Conn = $Conn;

    }

    public function dropGameView()
    {
        $drop = "DROP VIEW if EXISTS gameview;";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($drop);
        $stmt->execute(array());
    }
    public function createGameView()
    {
        $view = "CREATE VIEW gameview AS SELECT id, name, image, quote FROM person;";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($view);
        $stmt->execute(array());
    }

    public function useGameView()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * from gameview";
        $stmt = $this->Conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array());
        $gameView = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $gameView;
    }
}

?>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$gameView = new gameView($Conn);
$finalCharacter = $gameView->useGameView();
$smarty->assign('game_view', $finalCharacter);


?>
```

Comment: You're never calling `createGameView`

Comment: What possible reason could you need to drop the view each time?

Comment: I need it to drop each time the game is run.  The view is a list of characters that I need to iterate down to 1, and then the game can be restarted.

Comment: You don't need to drop it and recreate. A view is like a stored query (in a way) that is visible to you as a temporary table of sorts. If you need to refresh that results of that view, just query the view again. No need to drop/create -- that does nothing useful.

Comment: Yes, I do need a view.  I have many linking tables within the database.  The view is there to remove characters from the table until you're left with 1 character and displays that character at the end (it's basically a Star Wars Guess Who game that I'm doing for uni).  If the player wants to play again, I need that table reset.  If I create the view, delete characters from it, how will I get it to reload in it's original state?  I'm a relative novice to software development...

Answer (score 0):

Well....  stone the crows.  I thought this would be too simple to work, but it did!

```
<?php
$gameView = new gameView($Conn);
$dropGameView = $gameView->dropGameView();
$smarty->assign('drop_gameview', $dropGameView);
$createGameView = $gameView->createGameView();
$smarty->assign('create_gameview', $createGameView);
$finalCharacter = $gameView->useGameView();
$smarty->assign('game_view', $finalCharacter);


?>
```

Now to crack on and use the view.